# Whenever I click on any item on Powerbi dashboard, can the item be updated (number addition) on the SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerbi

I was trying to create a voting dashboard on Powerbi. Now I want to make that dashboard interactive with live voting. So whenever there is a click on any item of any column on that dashboard, I want number "1" or upvote to be updated on the same SharePoint list (that was used to make the powerBi dashboard) of that particular column whenever I submit that vote. For every submission of vote "1" value should be added on the SharePoint list. Can anyone help me with this task and how to perform this task using Power automate in PowerBi.